# Complex<double> in C++ - can't use imag(), complex(), real()

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

I have a problem when using functions from the complex.h
I have some numbers

```
typedef complex<double> cmplx;
cmplx N;
double x;
double y;
```

and now I need operations over them:

```
double k = real(N);
cmplx NI = complex(x,y);
double l = imag(N);
```

nothing from these works. What's wrong? I have tried to write creal, cimag, but nothing works... The compiler writes:

```
error: argument list for class template "std::complex" is missing
```

Please for your help

Thanks

---

EDIT

Thank you again for your help but now I have a new problem. If I have an array Arr[N] of cmplx numbers and now I need the real part of the Arr[i] I have written

```
realArray[5] = ComplexArray[5].real();
```

I get an error:

```
error: expression must have class type
```

the error is the same for real() or imag() functions

Comment: [A fine manual exists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: What does "nothing works" mean? You should include the error message you got from the compiler, in case you mean a compile error.

Comment: Please give a better definition of `does not work`

Comment: the error is: error: argument list for class template "std::complex" is missing

Comment: So you get that error from the second line; my answer explains why. What errors do you get from the first and third lines?

Comment: If you have a second question, then you should ask it as a second question. The code you've posted should be fine if `ComplexArray` is an array of `cmplx`. How exactly are `realArray` and `ComplexArray` declared?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I have a problem when using functions from the complex.h

There is no standard header with that name. I'll assume you mean `<complex>`; otherwise, you're including either a prehistoric or non-standard library, or the C library. In any case, you should change to `<complex>`.

The first and third lines should be fine. `real` and `imag` are defined both as non-member functions usable as you use them, or as member functions usable as `N.real()` and `N.imag()`.

The second line should be one of:

```
cmplx NI = cmplx(x,y);
cmplx NI = complex<double>(x,y);
cmplx NI(x,y);
```

either using your type alias `cmplx`, or the template specialisation itself, to specify the type. As the error says, you can't use a template where you need a type.

Comment: Please click the checkmark button next to the answer if Mike's answer was satisfactory.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```
double k = N.real();
cmplx NI = cmplx(x,y);
double l = N.imag();
```

Comment: `real` and `imag` are also non-member functions, so there should be no need to change those lines.